# Mock Relay-style pagination with Apollo Server

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a mock server using Apollo Server to return GraphQL responses. One of the queries is to get `teams` which has an array of `metrics` (see schema below):

```js
const mocks = {
  Query: () => ({
    teams: (/*parent, args, context, info*/) => teamsFixture,
  }),
};

const graphServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs: schema, mocks });
graphServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

And my query used to be (fields redacted):

```
teams {
  bpxId
  metrics {
    timestamp
  }
}
```

The real (java) server has changed this to allow me to query (**Relay** style) only the first item in the metrics array as it wasn't performant:

```
teams {
  bpxId
  metrics(first: 1) {
    edges {
      node {
        timestamp
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the response in this shape:

```
metrics: {
  edges: [
    {
      node: [Team]
      __typename: "TeamMetricsConnectionEdge"
    }
  ]
  __typename: "TeamMetricsConnection"
}
```

I want to add this capability to my Apollo Server mocks but not sure how?

New schema (relevant bits):

```
type TeamMetrics {
  timestamp: Int
  # etc
}

type TeamMetricsConnection {
  edges: [TeamMetricsConnectionEdge]
  pageInfo: PageInfo
}

type PageInfo {
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean!
  hasNextPage: Boolean!
  startCursor: String
  endCursor: String
}

type Query {
  teams(bpxId: Int): [Team]
}

type Team {
  bpxId: Int!
  metrics(first: Int! = 5, after: String): TeamMetricsConnection
}
```

How can I adjust my mock response to handle Relay pagination? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`graphql-relay`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js) to create mock resolver results. This could be an easy way to create pagination for static mock arrays. Use `connectionFromArray` to wrap an array of mocks to automatically create an object structure that fits the connection type. It is possible to access all the field arguments in the mock similarly how you would do it in a real resolver and pass them into the function.

I am not sure if this works when you call the function on a `MockList` though. Pagination is a bit tricky as well if the length of the results changes all the time (the `pageInfo.hasNextPage` might be mixed up and you might violate a lot of assumptions that Relay has according to the spec). So it might be fine to start with a simple static array if that satisfies your mocking needs.

Comment: Thanks I will check this out on Monday